# What kind of energy does gravity convert to?

Tags: gravity, energy-conservation

I know that energy doesn't disappear rather it just changes forms so that got me thinking to what kinds of energy can gravity be converted to and what is its most common conversion?

I'm not a physicist so I don't know if my whole question makes any sense but my best guess so far is that gravity turns to kinetic energy since the Earth is moving.

Comment: Depends on the mechanisms at play. In proto-planetary clouds it converts to heat and IR radiation, in the accretion zones of compact objects it can be radiation all the way into the x-ray and gamma ray energy range. Gravitational collapse can compress magnetic fields trapped in plasma (neutron stars and magnetars) and lead to very high energy acceleration mechanisms... nature is inventive. :-) Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes sense overall, but for the sake of discussion I need to tidy up the first part your question just a bit:

> What other forms of energy can *gravitational potential energy* be converted in to?

The short-and-sweet answer is that gravitational potential energy can be converted into any other form of energy.  The possibilities are limited only by your ability to imagine weird situations.

To answer the second part of your question -- again I need to tidy up the question just a bit:

> In everyday experiences, what are some of the more common forms of energy that gravitational potential energy gets converted into?

Given your mention of the Earth's orbit, I agree that kinetic energy is one of the more common "fates" of gravitational potential energy.

Lastly, I need to caution you that the Earth does not stay in motion around the sun in virtue of gravitational potential energy being continuously converted into kinetic energy (in case you were wondering).  But I'll leave this topic for future discussion if warranted.

Comment: Wellp it says here to avoid commenting stuff such as "thanks" but i cant upvote yet and i wanted to show you some gratitude. Thank you very much for answering with a simple and clear answer to each question

Answer (score 0):

By itself, in nature, gravitational potential only converts into kinetic energy. That can be falling of objects, rising of tides, or breaking of large bodies under tidal forces.

That kinetic energy can get converted into other (many) forms. For example -

1. When something falls under gravity and hits ground, some energy can convert into heat and sound etc. But that is due to the collision, not due to gravity. Gravity only imparted KE.
2. When something hits atmosphere at high speeds, some of KE gets converted into heat. Again, gravity only imparted KE.
3. We generate electricity from dams by using the KE, and thereafter can convert that electric energy into many other forms. But that is us, not gravity. Gravity only imparted KE.
4. Inside planets, gravity creates KE towards center, and matter no where to go, gets pressurized and thus heat is created. Gravity only tries to create motion (KE).
5. Inside stars, same thing, but the pressure/temperature gets so high that it initiates nuclear reaction. Gravity only causes pressure while trying to create KE, rest happens as a consequence.

and so on ..

Gravity by itself only contributes (or attempts) to KE. Rest are consequences. Which can be natural, or man designed.

Earth is moving due to KE that was imparted to it long back (in the begining). Now, sun's gravity just maintains it in orbit.

Again, sun's gravity is trying to impart KE to earth, but it is always in perpendicular direction to earth's path and so ends up only changing its direction. No change in energy, but another consequence is change in direction.

Hope this clarifies.

We can get into complecated scenarios like supernova, blackholes etc., but the concept is not going to change. Even gravitational waves are created by motion caused by gravity,